# How to calculate recency in R

Tags: r, rows, data-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(20)
round<-rep(1:10,2)
part<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
pay1<-sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
pay2<-sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
pay3<-sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
decs<-sample(1:3,20,replace=TRUE)
previous_max<-c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)
gamematrix<-cbind(part,game,round,pay1,pay2,pay3,decs,previous_max )
gamematrix<-data.frame(gamematrix)
```

Here is the output:

```
       part game round pay1 pay2 pay3 decs previous_max
1        1    1     1    9    5    6    2            0
2        1    1     2    8    1    1    1            1
3        1    1     3    3    5    5    3            0
4        1    1     4    6    1    5    1            0
5        1    1     5   10    3    8    3            0
6        1    2     6   10    1    5    1            0
7        1    2     7    1   10    7    3            0
8        1    2     8    1   10    8    2            1
9        1    2     9    4    1    5    1            0
10       1    2    10    4    7    7    2            0
11       2    1     1    8    4    1    1            0
12       2    1     2    8    5    5    2            0
13       2    1     3    1    9    3    1            1
14       2    1     4    8    2   10    2            1
15       2    1     5    2    6    2    3            1
16       2    2     6    5    5    6    2            0
17       2    2     7    4    5    1    2            0
18       2    2     8    2   10    5    2            1
19       2    2     9    3    7    3    2            1
20       2    2    10    9    3    1    1            0
```

How can I calculate a new indicator variable "previous_max",which returns  whether in the next round of the same game, the same participant choose the **maximal payoff** from the *previous* round. 
So I want something like follows:

Participant (part) 1:

In the first round of each game, previous_max is "0" (no previous round), in round 2, previous_max ="1", because in round 1, the maximal pay was max(pay1,pay2,pay3)=max(9,5,6)=9, and in round 2, the participant's decisions (decs) was 1 (which was the maximal value in previous round).

In round 3, previous_max=0, because the maximal value in round 2 was 8 (which is "pay1"), but the participant choose "3" (which is pay3).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `purr::map`.
I would have preferred to use `group_by` than split but `max.col` ignores groups and I don't know of a `dplyr` equivalent`.

the output is slightly different but I think it's because of your mistakes, please explain if not and I'll update my answer.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

  gamematrix       %>%
    split(.$part)  %>%
    map(~ .x %>% mutate(
      prev_max = as.integer( 
        decs == 
        c(0,max.col(.[c("pay1","pay2","pay3")])[-n()]) # the number of the max columns, offset by one
      ))) %>%
    bind_rows

  # `  part game round pay1 pay2 pay3 decs prev_max
  # 1     1    1     1    9    5    6    2        0
  # 2     1    1     2    8    1    1    1        1
  # 3     1    1     3    3    5    5    3        0
  # 4     1    1     4    6    1    5    1        0
  # 5     1    1     5   10    3    8    3        0
  # 6     1    2     6   10    1    5    1        1
  # 7     1    2     7    1   10    7    3        0
  # 8     1    2     8    1   10    8    2        1
  # 9     1    2     9    4    1    5    1        0
  # 10    1    2    10    4    7    7    2        0
  # 11    2    1     1    8    4    1    1        0
  # 12    2    1     2    8    5    5    2        0
  # 13    2    1     3    1    9    3    1        1
  # 14    2    1     4    8    2   10    2        1
  # 15    2    1     5    2    6    2    3        1
  # 16    2    2     6    5    5    6    2        1
  # 17    2    2     7    4    5    1    2        0
  # 18    2    2     8    2   10    5    2        1
  # 19    2    2     9    3    7    3    2        1
  # 20    2    2    10    9    3    1    1        0
```

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a magic! If you want the output to be as in my example, your code should be _slightly_ updated:   split(.,list(gamematrix$part,gamematrix$game))  %>%